# using other c++ compiler to compile the CUDA code

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc

I have a CUDA (*.cu) code compiled by nvcc, which is working pretty good in GPU. But nvcc doesn't support some c++11 features and some 3rd party c++ library cannot be used with nvcc. I wonder if it is possible to compile the .cu code with gcc or other commercial c++ compiler? Thanks.

Comment: If those C++11 features occur only in the host portion of your .cu file, I would suggest separating that code out into a separate file that is built directly with the host compiler. You may also want to file a feature request via the registered developer website for the C++11 features you use (C+11 added many diverse features, I assume your code just needs a few of them)

Comment: I think your first comment is what I am looking for. But there is a few lines of code using C++11 which is critical to the rest of the algorithm. It seems that I cannot separate it from the main code :(

Comment: check separate compilation in [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

nvcc supports explicitly specifying the host compiler it uses, togather with the host-compiler-specific options. You could find the doc on nvcc options `-ccbin` and `-Xcompiler` for details.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-command-options

For example, I bind nvcc with Intel compiler and Intel MKL as follows.

```
$ nvcc -ftz true -ccbin icpc -Xcompiler "-Wall -Wno-long-long -ansi -pedantic -ansi-alias -parallel -fopenmp -openmp-link=static -static-intel -wd10237" -O2 -Xcompiler "-O2"   -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -Ilib -c -o test/triangle.o test/triangle.cu
$ nvcc -ftz true -ccbin icpc -Xcompiler "-Wall -Wno-long-long -ansi -pedantic -ansi-alias -parallel -fopenmp -openmp-link=static -static-intel -wd10237" -O2 -Xcompiler "-O2"  -Ilib -Llib test/triangle.o lib/KTiming.o -lpthread -lm /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -lcublas -lcurand -lcusparse -o test/triangle
```

Comment: Worth noting that the intel compiler is only supported in CUDA 5.0 or newer on 64 bit Linux.

Comment: Thanks. I have cuda5.5 installed in linux 64bit OS and I try the first compile command but it reported that "nvcc fatal   : No input files specified; use option --help for more information
/opt/cuda5/include/host_config.h(72): catastrophic error: #error directive: -- unsupported ICC configuration! Only ICC 12.1 on Linux x86_64 is supported!
  #error -- unsupported ICC configuration! Only ICC 12.1 on Linux x86_64 is supported!
"

Comment: Officially cuda5.5 supports only Icc 12.1.  You could comment out the `#error` in /opt/cuda5/include/host_config.h(72). I haven't got any compile failure until now.

Comment: oh ... I am running the compilation in the cluster and everything were installed by IT. I don't have right to modify the code :( But thanks anyway

Comment: In fact, me too. I copied ..../cuda-5.5 to my home and defined `$CUDA_HOME` and added `$PATH`,`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my `.bashrc`. Then I have the full control of cuda-5.5